# Understanding crontab entry

Tags: unix

I've got this Unix script and I'm trying to translate it to Python. The problem is I don't understand Unix and I have no idea what any of it means.

This is the code:

```
1 17-23 * * * curl -X PUT -d EM_OperatingMode=10 --header 'Auth-Token: 512532eb-0d57-4a59-8da0-e1e136945ee8' http://192.168.1.70:80/api/v2/configurations
```

Comment: That's not a script, that is a crontab entry, read the man page for it regards the `1 17-23 * * *` part. You only need decipher `curl -X PUT -d EM_OperatingMode=10 --header 'Auth-Token: 512532eb-0d57-4a59-8da0-e1e136945ee8' http://192.168.1.70:80/api/v2/configurations`. If it works, why do you feel the need to convert it to python?

Comment: If you want to convert that cron job to Python then I recommend that you familiarise yourself with the *requests* module. That would be for a "pure" Python approach. You can, of course, invoke *curl* from Python but that would be pointless in this case

Comment: @Bib I am able to program in python and the guy who gave me the crontab asked if I could translate it into python, this is the only part of the crontab that I cant translate because I simply don't know the python equivalents or even what each part does to begin with

Comment: ask "the guy" whether he knows it's a crontab entry and does he expect you to reimplement a cron daemon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be cron job that runs given command automatically on the given interval: "At minute 1 past every hour from 17 through 23."

Similar Python code would be

```py
import requests

requests.put(
  "http://192.168.1.70:80/api/v2/configurations", 
  data={"EM_OperatingMode":10}, 
  headers={"Auth-Token":"512532eb-0d57-4a59-8da0-e1e136945ee8"}
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you took is in crontab of Unix system. Let's split the code into two parts.

The first part, `1 17-23 * * *` , represents a schedule. It means between 17:00 to 23:00, the program runs every hour at the first minute of that hour. Crontab follows min hour day month weekday. (Refer [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#1_17-23_*_*_*).)

The second part, `curl -X PUT -d EM_OperatingMode=10 --header 'Auth-Token: 512532eb-0d57-4a59-8da0-e1e136945ee8' http://192.168.1.70:80/api/v2/configurations`, represents a PUT request to an URL.

curl is a program used to communicate with a server. You use a browser to interact with a server right. You can think of curl as a command line tool to do the same. The parameter contains PUT request which updates data in the server. Here `EM_OperationMode=10` is being passed to the server for updating. `--header` represents parameters to be sent to the URL. Here an authentication token is being sent to the URL to validate its access. Finally, the URL for communication is `http://192.168.1.70:80/api/v2/configurations`.

So, the value is being passed to the server at 192.168.1.70 as per the schedule I mentioned above. You can use Python requests library to replicate the server communication while you can retain the scheduler for calling the python program to run it as per the same schedule.

Answer (score -1):

It is `crontab`, example:

```
*    *    *   *    *  Command_to_execute
|    |    |    |   |       
|    |    |    |    Day of the Week ( 0 - 6 ) ( Sunday = 0 )
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    Month ( 1 - 12 )
|    |    |
|    |    Day of Month ( 1 - 31 )
|    |
|    Hour ( 0 - 23 )
|

Min ( 0 - 59 )
```

Here is the source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm

And second part is `curl` with some options (flags): https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html